# How to turn off pagination for a particular viewset in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is a snippet of the code that I tried to disable pagination as suggested in answers to similar questions. But this is not working for me. I even tried overriding the default `paginate_queryset` method but ended up observing that it wasn't even getting called(maybe I am doing it the wrong way)

```
class TestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Test.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TestSerializer
    filter_backends = (django_filters.DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter)
    filterset_fields = {'status': ('exact', 'in'), }
    search_fields = ['=id', ]
    pagination_class = None
```

Below is also the code I tried to override `paginate_queryset`

```
def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, view=None):
        if 'no_page' in request.query_params:
            return None

        return super().paginate_queryset(queryset, request, view)
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
class TestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Test.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TestSerializer
    filter_backends = (django_filters.DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter)
    filterset_fields = {'status': ('exact', 'in'), }
    search_fields = ['=id', ]
    paginator = None  # -- add this
    #pagination_class = None  # -- remove this
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
@property
def paginator(self):
    self._paginator = super(TestViewSet, self).paginator
    if self.action == 'the_action_you_want_pagination_disabled':
        self._paginator = None
    return self._paginator
```

Answer (score 0):

Django Rest Framework docs state that:
Pagination can be turned off by setting the pagination class to None.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/

I have tried this and it works for me:

```
pagination_class = None
```